# ! You can't use `\eqno' in math mode

Tags: math-mode, equations, braces

what is wrong with this??? please,can anyone help?

```
\begin{equation} \label{probabilityy}
P^{t}({E_{0})=P_{0}+(1-P_{0})P_{1}+ (1-P_{0})(1-P_{1})P_{2}+.......+P_{n}\Pi_{k_{0}}^{n-1}(1-P_{k})
\end{equation}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's really not applicable to a wider audience (due to a typo).

Comment: Au contraire – this is actually quite a _useful_ question, because the error message is regrettably such a useless one: ‘of _course_ I can use `\eqno` in a maths mode – that's the point!’ that it distracts from the real problem.  You can't use `\eqno` in an _inner_ maths mode, and _that's_ what TeX's objecting to.  Ie, this is a silly brace matching error, but I didn't realise the problem when I hit it, until I found this question (doh!). The similar questions elsewhere on the site are less useful, because they distract with too many other errors.  Sooooo, yet another 10 points for David.

Comment: @NormanGray thanks:-) you can vote for re-open

Comment: It could be a missing \right) too giving the error as in the title.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have a spurious extra `{`

```
P^{t}({E_{
      ^
```

Comment: oh yeah!. thanks!. thanks for the quick and clear answer!.