# ! You can't use `\eqno' in math mode. couldn't find a solution in similar threads

Tags: math-mode, arrays

```
\begin{equation}  
f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ; x \mapsto  
\left \{ \begin{array}{cc}  
|x|^{3} , &  \text{für}\ x  \lvertneqq 1 ; \\\  
x^{2} , & \text{für}\ 1 \leqslant x \lvertneqq 2 ; \\\  
x^{4} \cdot 2 , & \text{für}\ 2 \leqslant x .  
\end{array}  
\end{equation}
```

Can somebody please explain my error?

Using the following packages

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Comment: you don't have any `\right` command: you should add `\right.` after `\end{array}`.

Comment: @ebo Same error yes, but different cause, right?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. yes, my bad... I actually wanted to flag [regarding this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/182950/64454)... but even then, even if issues are more similar (missing opening/closing bracket), answers is not really duplicable.

Answer (score 3):

Every `\left` needs a `\right`: add `\right.` after the `array`.

You might be interested in the `cases` environment though, which is made for constructs like that:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}  
f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ; x \mapsto  
\left \{ \begin{array}{cc}  
|x|^{3} , &  \text{für}\ x  \lvertneqq 1 ; \\\  
x^{2} , & \text{für}\ 1 \leqslant x \lvertneqq 2 ; \\\  
x^{4} \cdot 2 , & \text{für}\ 2 \leqslant x .  
\end{array}  \right.
\end{equation}
With \texttt{cases}
\begin{equation}  
f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ; x \mapsto  
\begin{cases}  
|x|^{3} , &  \text{für}\ x  \lvertneqq 1 ; \\
x^{2} , & \text{für}\ 1 \leqslant x \lvertneqq 2 ; \\
x^{4} \cdot 2 , & \text{für}\ 2 \leqslant x .  
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}  
\end{document}
```

[image]