# while writing equation i am getting 'You can't use `\eqno' in math mode. \end{equation}' error...why?

Tags: equations

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
%\documentclass[num-refs]{wiley-article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}



\begin{document}


\title{gffjttymtdymt}


\author{Kp~Yadav,
        Pv~Dai}
    


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Small signal stability analysis of the power system is mandatory because slowly growing oscillations may end with the blackout of the system. 
\end{abstract}


\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Static Var Compensator, CPSS-Conventional Power System Stabilizer, POD- Power Oscillation Damping, Residue Factor, Participation Factor.
\end{IEEEkeywords}


\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle



\section{INTRODUCTION}
The modern power system is highly interconnected to meet increasing energy demand and to utilize available sources adequately. The interconnection of the power system is necessary for reliable and flexible operation, so the power system needs to be stable against small or large disturbances such as faults, disconnection of large loads or generators, etc. The stability of the system is strongly influenced by the dynamic behavior of components of the system like generators, loads and other control equipment (FACTs devices).
The disturbances in the system cause change in the electrical torque of the synchronous machine [1]. The change in electrical torque due to disturbances can be divided into two parts and is described by :
\begin{equation}\label{1}
\Delta {T_e} = \Delta {T_{es}}\Delta \delta  + \Delta {T_{eD}}\Delta \omega 
\end{equation}
The analysis of power system oscillations is of interest in a system where the number of generators are working in parallel for supplying power to a common load. In this type of condition, generators produce torques. These torques act to keep the generators in synchronism (synchronizing torque). 

\section{MATHEMATICAL MODELING OF SYSTEM} \label{modelingofstudysystem}
In this section each component of multimachine test system is model in the mathematical form as follows: 
\subsection{Synchronous Machine}
The synchronous machine is modeled in the form of equations includes swing equation, rotor and stator voltage equations as follows:
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\frac{{d\delta }}{{dt}} = {\omega _B}({s_m} - {s_{mo}})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq3}
\frac{{d{s_m}}}{{dt}} = \frac{1}{{2H}}[ - D({s_m} - {s_{mo}}) + {T_m} - {T_e}]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq4}
\frac{{d{E^'}_q}}{{dt}} = \frac{1}{{{T^'}_{do}}}[ - {E^'}_q + ({x_d} - x{'_d}) + {E_{fd}}]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq5}
\frac{{d{E^'}_d}}{{dt}} = \frac{1}{{{T^'}_{qo}}}[ - {E^'}_d - ({x_q} - x{'_q}){i_q}]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq6}
{T_e} = {E^'}_q{i_q} + {E^'}_d{i_d} + (x{'_d} - x{'_q}){i_d}{i_q}
\end{equation}


\section{Conclusion} \label{conclusion}
Power system oscillations can lead the system towards the shutdown. Hence, to damp out these 


\end{document}
```

Comment: If I try to compile your example document, I get a bunch of "Missing { inserted."  error messages.

Comment: Yes.. But i have put equations correctly.

Comment: As long as you get error messages upon compiling your document, somethign is still wrong with the code. The combination of `^'`, for example in `{E^'}_q` causes the error messages. Depending on the expected output, something like `E^{'}_{q}` or `E'_{q}` should help you get rid of the error message.

Comment: Yess... it solved the error. Thanks alot..

Comment: Instead of the symbol ' use {\sp{\prime}.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [! You can't use \`\eqno' in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182950/you-cant-use-eqno-in-math-mode)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by comments.

Comment: @V.Nikolaidis why would anyone want to write `\sp{\prime}` instead of  `'` (which makes the same output)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle \sp for the superscript
\prime for the ' ...
I do not see why not? OK, It is not the fastest workaround to tackle the problem, but the result which I tested it is the same... I thought the problem was on line 65 (eq4) if I remember correctly because of the ' when I tested the code... this was my understanding ...

Comment: `'` expands to `^\{prime}` and `\sp` is `\let` to `^` so `\sp{\prime}`  will do the same thing as `'` but takes 11 characters instead of one.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You have bunch of errrs in your (last three) equations

- instead of `${E^'}_{d}$` is correct `$E'_{d}$` or `$E'_d$`
- you have far too much curly braces in your equations, consequently it is easy to lost in it ...

Complete (real) MWE:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{1}
\Delta {T_e} = \Delta {T_{es}}\Delta \delta  + \Delta {T_{eD}}\Delta \omega
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\frac{{d\delta }}{{dt}} = {\omega _B}({s_m} - {s_{mo}})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq3}
\frac{{d{s_m}}}{{dt}} = \frac{1}{{2H}}[ - D({s_m} - {s_{mo}}) + {T_m} - {T_e}]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq4}
\frac{d E'_q}{dt} = \frac{1}{T'_{do}}[ - E'_q +  (x_d - x'_d) + E_{fd}]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq5}
\frac{dE'_d}{dt} = \frac{1}{T'_{qo}}[ - E'_d - (x_q - x'_q) i_q]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq6}
T_e = E'_q i_q + E'_d i_d + (x'_d - x'_q) i_d i_q
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
According to @egreg comment your equations my be written as:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather} % <---
\Delta {T_e} = \Delta {T_{es}}\Delta \delta  + \Delta {T_{eD}}\Delta \omega
    \label{1}      \\
\frac{{d\delta }}{{dt}} = {\omega _B}({s_m} - {s_{mo}})
    \label{eq2}     \\
\frac{{d{s_m}}}{{dt}} = \frac{1}{{2H}}[ - D({s_m} - {s_{mo}}) + {T_m} - {T_e}]
    \label{eq3}     \\
\frac{d E'_q}{dt} = \frac{1}{T'_{do}}[ - E'_q +  (x_d - x'_d) + E_{fd}]
    \label{eq4}     \\
\frac{dE'_d}{dt} = \frac{1}{T'_{qo}}[ - E'_d - (x_q - x'_q) i_q]
    \label{eq5}     
\intertext{and finally:}
T_e = E'_q i_q + E'_d i_d + (x'_d - x'_q) i_d i_q
    \label{eq6}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also there should be `gather` rather than multple `equation` environments.

Comment: @egreg, of course. I just collect all equation assuming that between can be some text not present in OP provided document. Anyway, I will add option with `gather` asap.